# WP Admin menu item hides when other plugin is enabled

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, admin

I am supposed to copy an already existing plugin, and make it work with a different service provider, So what I did was copy all the files from the original plugin, and string replaced "carefully" all the unique strings to a counterpart strings and then voila the plugin started successfully. Now I had to do a minor set of changes in terms of how the plugin handles the new third party API, which I was able to accomplish successfully.

Now I am stuck at just one point, and thats it!!! Everything else works just fine.

The menu Item that the plugins create is some how still connected with each other, even though I have thoroughly screened through all the files and different menu adding functions but still what happenes is that...

When the original plugin is active then the menu Item for the new plugin just doesnt show up. BUT when I disable the original plugin, then the menu Item for the new plugin shows up!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ahh, How much I like to answer my own question,

The culprit was the `menu_position` in the array of arguments `$args`

```
   $args = array(
        'labels' => $labels,
        'public' => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => false,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'show_in_menu' => true,
        'query_var' => true,
        'capability_type' => 'post',
        'has_archive' => false,
        'hierarchical' => false,
        'menu_position' => 15,  // <== Culprit
        'register_meta_box_cb' => array('mf_bridge_post_type', 'do_admin_metaboxes'),
        'supports' => array('title')
    );
```

While copying both the menu items were positioned as `null` which was creating a conflict and hence the confusion.